# documentUrlPatterns not respecting pathnames

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, firefox-addon-webextensions, safari-web-extension, web-extension

I am running into some issues when attempting to use [`documentUrlPatterns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create) with my web extension, *on Safari*, when [creating context menu items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create).

**Example:**

`browser.contextMenus.create({id: "12354", title: "Test01",documentUrlPatterns:["https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"]});`

When using `documentUrlPatterns` on any website with an explicit `pathname` (as shown above), the context menu item does *not* get created for [matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) document urls.

With the above code I would expect to see a context menu item on `https://www.linkedin.com/feed/` with the title `Test01`, but nothing appears. As mentioned, it seems any *explicit* path name, such as `/feed/` or `/someother/page/` on *any* website presents this issue.

My understanding of how [matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) works makes me think that explicit path names are valid in patterns, but perhaps I am missing something.

If I drop the last trailing slash `/`, the context menu item seems to be created as expected.

Is my expected outcome valid or is there something unique about the way `documentUrlPatterns` works that I am missing?

The above code seems to work as intended in Chrome and Firefox. I imagine this could be an Apple Safari related bug but before reporting it, I was curious if there's something I am missing.

Comment: Looks like the [trailing slash matters](https://searchfacts.com/url-trailing-slash/) so there seems to be a bug in Safari.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, I think you're right. I posted it in the Apple forums to see if there is some idiosyncrasy, but if Apple's goal is to have Safari Web Extensions function like Chrome and Firefox, then there's certainly something wrong.